# Search NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array with dictionaries,
and need to search trough the array

and modify a specific dictionary in the array found by an object name inside the dictionary.

So , create the mutable array, dictionary , and add many dictionaries to the array

```
       ...{ self.bloquesArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];  
    [self createBloqueDicto];
    [self.unBloqueDicto setObject:@"easySprite" forKey:@"Name"];
    [self.unBloqueDicto setObject:@"290" forKey:@"X"];
    [self.unBloqueDicto setObject:@"300" forKey:@"Y"];

    [self.bloquesArray addObject:self.unBloqueDicto];

}

- (void)createBloqueDicto {
self.unBloqueDicto = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

so now I need to change the value for the key X and Y in the dictionary with

key: Name = easySprite
so need to find that specific dictionary [other dictionaries have different values for Name]

how can I do this please?

thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do the following to get the matched dictionaries,

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name = %@", @"easySprite"];
NSArray *matchedDicts = [bloquesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Now the *matchedDicts* contains the dictionaries with the value **@"easySprite"** for the key **@"Name"**. Do the rest(changing the X and Y) from there.

Comment: that is awesome thanks, to see the content of the dictionary in another array, but how can I please know what is the index for that dictionary? and modify that specific dictionary?, thanks!

Comment: You can not edit a dictionary which is in an array. First get the dictionary, create a new dictionary with new values, delete the old dictionary from the array, and add the new dictionary to the array.

Comment: @EmptyStack, unless the elements of the NSArray are already NSMutableDictionary... his `unBloqueDicto` is an NSMutableDictionary, so it *is* mutable.