# Searching an NSArray of NSDictionaries to verify information

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` full of `NSDictionary` object. This structure is built from a database. I'm building a verification function that is only included and executed when debugging. The idea is to make sure all the files need are in fact included and any extra files are not included.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340694/search-nsarray-of-nsdictionaries) question I tried to use a `NSPredicate` but its flagging every file in thr directory as "File not in Database".

What am I doing wrong?

`KEY_DFILE` is #defined as `@"dFilename"`.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
- (void)checkItems
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSLog(@"-------- Database / File Check --------");
    for (NSDictionary* item in self.allItmes)
    {
        // ansi items
        if ([[item objectForKey:KEY_TYPE] isEqualToString:@"ansi"])
        {
            // Make sure the datafile exists
            NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[item objectForKey: KEY_DFILE] ofType:nil inDirectory:@"ansi"];
            if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
                NSLog(@"Can't find file: %@", path);
        }
    }

    NSString *dir = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ansi"];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:dir];
    NSString* file;
    while (file = [en nextObject])
    {
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", KEY_DFILE, file];
        NSArray *matchedDicts = [self.allItmes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
        if ([matchedDicts count] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"File not in Database: %@", file);
        }
        else if ([matchedDicts count] > 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"File in Database more than once: %@", file);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"---------------------------------------");
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", KEY_DFILE, file];
```

To this:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", KEY_DFILE, file];
```

The %K says that the argument is a dynamic property name and not a string (so it doesn't quote it).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your predicate format to be "%K == %@".